# Через что лучше реализовать простенькие, но частовстречающиеся индикаторы - css или svg

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

У меня есть куча картинок, рядом с которыми я хочу показать по 2 индикатора (символизируют характеристики 0..100уе объектов, указанных на картинках, но при этом не такие важные, чтобы отображать это цифрами).

Встал вопрос - как лучше это сделать.
Выделил 2 способа:

**через html и css:**

```
<div class = info id = 'o011'><span class = 'i1'></span><span class = 'i2'></span></div>
```

и через JS менять ширину span'ов для конкретного id

**через svg**

```
<svg class = info id = 'o011'></svg>
```

и через JS перерисовывать 2 полоски внутри svg с нужной длиной

Какой подход более удобен/целесообразен/оптимален?

С одной стороны svg подход меньше кода внутри html обеспечивает, с другой - css более нагляден.

**P.S.**

Подумалось, что если и так знаю, что у меня только 2 индикатора на `.info`, то если использовать css html код будет довольно коротким:

```
<div class = info id = 'o011'><span></span><span></span></div>
```

Хотя конечно в управлении доступом к этим span'ам через jQuery придется несколько страшные запросы писать с `:first-child`.

Comment: А можно картинку того, что вы реализовываете?

Comment: примерно вот так: http://www.picshare.ru/view/8391526/

Comment: А почему вы не можете сразу сгенерировать html, в котором будет указана ширина, чтобы не гонять лишний раз JS?

Answer (score 1):

Решение зависит от того, в каком виде выдаются для вас данные. Если  вы планируете все вручную вводить и изображений не так много, тогда можете использовать данный способ.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Вам нужна только эта часть */

div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: green;
}

div:after {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 25px;
}

div:nth-child(1):before {
  width: 80px;
}

div:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(2):before {
  width: 30px;
}

div:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.suckerpunchdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SSC-Tuatara1_FRONT.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.suckerpunchdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SSC-Tuatara.jpg">
</div>
```

Используя ID или при помощи `:nth-chld()` задавайте ширину для псевдоэлементов от нуля до 100рх. Или в процентах. Принцип, думаю, понятен.

Решение для двух и более полос:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Вам нужна только эта часть */

div span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: green;
}

div span:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 25px;
}

div span:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="width:80px"></span>
  <span style="width:50px"></span>
  <img src="http://www.suckerpunchdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SSC-Tuatara1_FRONT.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <span style="width:70px"></span>
  <span style="width:30px"></span>
  <span style="width:100px"></span>
  <img src="http://www.suckerpunchdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SSC-Tuatara.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: у этого способа есть огромный недостаток - он стационарен. я не знаю способа каким можно обратиться к :before, :after элементам, т.е. чтобы у 10 разных картинок было 10 разных индикаторов (по значениям) и для этого не пришлось бы создавать разные css стили. Ну и второй недостаток - этот способ создает только максимум 2 индикатора, если надо создать 3 - уже проблемы.

Comment: @Zhihar вы показали картинку, я предложил решение. Если бы там было 3 полоски, я бы поставил туда какой-нить тег. Что касается стационарности, я написал, что нужно знать в каком виде вы получаете данные. Как по мне, проще всего сделать объект со всеми данными и используя их создать необходимую структуру при помощи JS.

Comment: Повторюсь. Все зависит от ситуации. Если у вас тысячи позиций и множество параметром, JS вам в помощь. Если это частный случай, делайте все при помощи CSS.

Comment: Да - именно про кучу позиций и говорил (куча картинок у которых индивидуальные индикаторы) - т.е. добавлять по 2 div им и манипулировать через JS или 1 svg и манипулировать через JS

Comment: @Zhihar тогда проще всего через style регулировать ширину. Пример такой добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, зачем так все усложнять, если вы можете передать эти значения сразу в разметку.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}
.info {
width: 100px;
margin: 10px;
}
span {
height: 10px;
display: block;
width: 0;
margin: 2px 0;
}
.i1 {
background-color: red;
}
.i2 {
background-color: green;
}
.i3 {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class = 'info' id = 'o011'>
  <span class = 'i1' style="width: 50%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i2' style="width: 34%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i3' style="width: 100%;"></span>
  </div>

  <div class = 'info' id = 'o011'>
  <span class = 'i1' style="width: 40%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i2' style="width: 78%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i3' style="width: 15%;"></span>
  </div>

  <div class = 'info' id = 'o011'>
  <span class = 'i1' style="width: 67%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i2' style="width: 19%;"></span>
  <span class = 'i3' style="width: 36%;"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery подход:

```js
var $images = $(".image"),
    dt,
    j,
    step_plus = 11;
    colors = ["red","blue","green","purple"];

$images.each(function() {

    dt = $(this).data();
    step = 0;
    j = 0;
    
    for(var i in dt){
    
       $(this).append("<span class='indicator' style='bottom:" + step + "px;background-color:" + colors[j] + ";width:" + dt[i] + "px'></span>");
       dt[i];
       
       step += step_plus;
       
       j++;
       
    }
    
});
```

```css
.image{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:lightgray;
    margin:5px;
}
.indicator{
    position:absolute;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image" data-indicator-one="50" data-indicator-two="50"></div>
<div class="image" data-indicator-one="75" data-indicator-two="50"></div>
<div class="image" data-indicator-one="16" data-indicator-two="30"></div>
<div class="image" data-indicator-one="50" data-indicator-two="22" data-indicator-three="56"></div>
```

Comment: т.е. выбран первый вариант - через html теги